# Kubuntu - The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: kubuntu

I'm trying to install pipelight, however I keep getting this issue.

```
The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```